# Air-Water mix flow and pressure

Tags: water, air

I'm using a system that creates water and air jets. 
The air line pressure is constant at 1.5 bar while the flow rate changes between 100-2500 cm³. 
The mixing is done with a water pump that operates at 255 rpm and around 500 cm³ of water flow.
I want to calculate the output pressure of the mix (water and flow).

How can I calculate it?

Comment: Flow rate would be volume per unit time, here just states a volume. What is the flow rate for these?

Comment: is it cc per minute, ccm?

Comment: with a given flow rate, pressure would depend on outlet diameter, smaller outlet, more restriction, greater pressure to maintain flow rate

Comment: What is this air/water mixture exhausting to?  The downstream pressure on your device will have a huge effect on the answer.  In addition, a picture would be a big help.